# Assertion error while creating a derived column in a spark DataFrame by splitting a string column by a delimiter

Tags: python, pyspark, split, assertion

I am trying to run this code, creating a new column in the spark DataFrame based on a string column X which contains 'asdf-fsdg-fgh' like strings or None or blanks

```
def len_split(x):
    try:
      k=len(x.split('-')) if '-' in x else 0
    except:
      k=0
    return k
  
  
dat = dat.withColumns("n_X", udf(len_split, 'int')("X"))
```

however, I am getting an assertion error:

```
   2608         # Below code is to help enable kwargs in future.
-> 2609         assert len(colsMap) == 1
   2610         colsMap = colsMap[0]  # type: ignore[assignment]
   2611 

AssertionError:
```

Can anyone help on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using withColumn instead of withColumns

```
def len_split(x):
    try:
      k=len(x.split('-')) if '-' in x else 0
    except:
      k=0
    return k
  
  
dat = dat.withColumn("n_X", udf(len_split, 'int')("X"))
```

Edit - Also don't know why you are expecting an exception and using UDF for simple function but as Udf is slower than spark functions for same functionality below code will also work

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
dat = dat.withColumn("n_X", F.when(col("X").contains("-"),F.size(F.split("X","-"))).otherwise(0))
```